# Getting authentication error in google map android application

Tags: android, google-maps

I made a simple android application to show the google map in my application where I am getting the authentication error from google server. Below I am giving my application files details.

1.AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mygooglemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mygooglemap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCmh6y3ASg53-ro7VAfYsGv4z0VknlykPU" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

2.MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mygooglemap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

3.activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me to run the application successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the for signing the application the same certificate you used to generate the SHA1 key for the API key. I made the same mistake, to generate a key from another certificate and sign the application with another.

In your case, I believe you should've get the key from the test certificate.